# Visual Studio 2017 failed to locate cl.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I recently installed Visual Studio 2017 and need to change something in a C++ project.

But when I try to build, it says cl.exe is missing. None of the solutions provided online seem to work.

I do have a cl.exe, but it is located under this path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64
```

I have also tried running `vcvars32.bat`, but that does not seem to make any changes.

And I have installed 'Desktop development with C++'.

Comment: The c,c++ compilers are not installed during the Visual Studio installation by default. Have you checked the c++ development tools during VS installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by running `vcvars.bat`.

For Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 it is located under the following directory:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext`

Comment: After running this command, `cl.exe` still doesn't seem to be recognized for some reason.

Comment: I tried this and I get an error `Cannot find common files`